# Why are Typed Arrays causing Memoryleaks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, garbage-collection

I noticed that i get this Error when trying to create many `Float32Arrays`:

> Uncaught RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed

I tried to reproduce the error like this:

```
console.log("trying to cause memory leaks");
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    console.log(i);
    var x = new Float32Array(100000000);
  //var x = new Array(100000000);
}
console.log("finished");
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

And as far as I understand the concept of the garbage collector, he should collect and dump unlinked objects. But since Im getting the error mentioned above I dont think it works as expected. Nevertheless there are no problems when I do the same thing with an `Array` instead of a `Float32Array`. I can even scale the numbers up with `Array`.
So maybe I am illinformed about the garbage collector or there is something fishy about the `Float32Array` constructor. Maybe my test lacks integrity, ie. the garbage collector has not enough time to collect, or sth trivial like that?

Maybe someone can give me some insight?

PS: Im using Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m which uses the V8 engine afaik

Comment: It's not a memory leak when it isn't retaining memory unncessarily. Or are you saying that the browser's RAM usage doesn't go down after throwing the exception?

Comment: If you use an `Array`, it's sparse until you fill it; it would only consist of a `length` property with a large value. If you use a `Float32Array`, it will need to allocate 400MB at once.

Comment: At which iteration of your loop is it failing? And how much memory does your browser have allocated until then?

Comment: is that 32 or 64bit chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Nevertheless there are no problems when I do the same thing with an `Array` instead of a `Float32Array`. I can even scale the numbers up with `Array`.

`new Array(100000000)` doesn't allocate anything but an array object with a `length` property. That's it. No element slots are created, because standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) *(that's a post on my blog)*, they're just objects backed by `Array.prototype` with a special `length` property and special handling of properties whose names meet the spec's definition of "array indexes" (details in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects)).

In contrast, `new Float32Array(100000000)` has to allocate contiguous memory for 100,000,000 32-bit slots (plus the object overhead). So if there isn't a contiguous block of 400,000,000 bytes available for that buffer, it's going to fail.

---

Side note: I was able to run your loop to completion in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) on *nix. Took a while, but... No memory leaks showed up, system memory use looked like this while it was running (the flatline at the beginning is before I started it, I've chopped it off long before it finished, it would be *way* too wide otherwise):

[image]

We can see that V8 (the JavaScript engin in Chrome) would let some garbage pile up, then run GC and clean up some unreferenced `Float32Array`s, then let garbage pile up, then GC, etc. No leak.

Chrome's task manager showed this usage:

```
Before starting:                 58,000k
While running:    3,700,000 - 5,100,000k
At end:                         450,000,
```

...which makes sense since nothing clears `x` at the end of the loop, so it's still referencing that last array.

Comment: so how came it that i got that error on the 5th iteration? since you said it should be garbage collected, there shouldnt be a problem, right?

Comment: @InsOp: Well, I can't replicate the error, so... I assumed your real code was retaining the references. Perhaps if you [answered this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333824/why-are-typed-arrays-causing-memoryleaks-in-javascript/39333895?noredirect=1#comment65999163_39333824).